# Django - Allow custom users edit their profile

Tags: python, django

I think I've tried all the solutions from Internet to allow custom users to edit their profile but I still can't manage to do it.

To illustrate my architecture, I have a profile page on which there is an edit button. This button open a modal form to edit the profile. I think I have to do something with my url (to include pk in it) but I don't understand how : if I use a simple path (without pk) I have this error :
[Reverse for 'edit_profile_modal' not found. 'edit_profile_modal' is not a valid view function or pattern name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEC1n.png) and when I try to add pk I have this one : [Reverse for 'edit_profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/edit_profile/(?P[0-9]+)$']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHdAu.png)

Here is my code :

accounts/url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('profil/', ProfileView.as_view(), name="profil"),
    path('edit_profile/',EditProfileView.as_view(),name="edit_profile"),]
```

views.py

```
class EditProfileView(BSModalUpdateView):
    model = Account
    template_name = 'accounts:edit_profile'
    form_class = EditProfileForm
    success_message = 'Le profil a été modifié avec succès'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:profil')
```

profil.html

```
<!--Modal-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#edit-profile").modalForm({
            formURL: "{% url 'accounts:edit_profile' %}"
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="edit-profile" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button"><a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'accounts:edit_profile_modal'%}">Editer »</a></button>
```

edit_profile_modal.html

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Update Account</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="{% if form.non_field_errors %}invalid{% endif %} mb-2">
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
            {% render_field field class="form-control" placeholder=field.label %}
            <div class="{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div><form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Update Account</h3>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="{% if form.non_field_errors %}invalid{% endif %} mb-2">
                {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                     {{ error }}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                {% render_field field class="form-control" placeholder=field.label %}
                <div class="{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</div>
```

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(BSModalModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['email', 'username','prenom','nom','birthday']
```

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=30)  
    birthday = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=now)

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['prenom', 'nom']

    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    birthday = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def getFirstNameAndName(self):
        return self.prenom +" "+self.nom
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html you have:

`href="{% url 'accounts:edit_profile_modal'%}`

But in your urls you call it `edit_profile`

So changing that plus adding the `pk` would give:

`href="{% url 'accounts:edit_profile' pk=object_pk %}`

And change your url to:
`path('edit_profile/<int:pk>',EditProfileView.as_view(),name="edit_profile")`

Comment: Okay I understand that but how does it sends me to my modal then ? I think I should modify it to  href="{% url 'accounts/edit_profile_modal.html' pk=object_ok %} no ? Moreover, I still have the same error ( I also tried with this line in url.py : path('edit_profile/<int:pk>',EditProfileView.as_view(),name="edit_profile"))

Comment: It has to be of the form `{% url 'accounts:<name of url>' %}` and I don't see a path with that name.

Comment: Yes but then should I modify my url name to add a link to my modal ?